# ionic: what is faster? doing computation/sorting in Typescript or in Android/Java

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I have more then 1500 users in roomdb. I want to sort users and also filter them with provided text. (User object have firstname, lastname, image(base64),nickname)

my question is: what is best way and fast way of doing so in Ionic?

1. Getting data from android roomdb with sorting and then loop over it to filter users in java. Then send result with JSArray to angular. ---OR---
2. Get all users once from roomdb, send to angular and now sorting them or filtering them in typescript, whenever user change sorting

(in first type I have to query every time to roomdb whenever sorting is changed or search text is changed but in second type i don't, as I have already all the Users object. But Second type could block UI as looping might take some time)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to think in terms of space more than in terms of CPU.

Sorting 1500 users is not that much nowadays but loading 1500 base64 images can be huge for a smartphone or a navigator.

In database, it's often a good practice to filter soon. And it's probably the way to follow for your problem, the third solution is to filter through SQL so before Typescript and before Java.